Asymptote and PDF version 1.4
Since version 2.88, Asymptote produces PDF version 1.5 (announcement).
I need to produce a PDF version 1.4 with LaTeX. When I use the pdf14 package in LaTeX, I get
a warning pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figure.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.5>, but at most version <1.4> allowed
Is there a way to force Asymptote to produce PDF version 1.4?
I tried adding
usepackage("pdf14");
in my Asymptote source file and it didn’t have any effect.

why did you need to produce 1.4??

Why are you using the pdf14 package in the first place?

I don’t want, but the publisher wants to.

There are several tools to prost-process PDF. For example, you can use ps2pdf14 infile.pdf outfile.pdf (yes, it can also read PDF not only PS, because it is a ghostscript script) or Adobe Acrobat or …

@close voters: I agree it is a bit borderline but I think it is on-topic: the question asks how to include an Asymptote-produced pdf with a particular LaTeX package. Voting to leave open.
